# How to specify the path of an attachment stored on a different computer in the same network

Tags: sql-server, database-mail

I'm trying to send an email through SQL Server. The sp_send_dbmail has a parameter to specify the path of a file to send as an attachment. It works perfectly when the file is in the same server where SQL Server is hosted. However, I need to send a file that is stored on another server or computer in the same network.

How can I specify the path for such file?

Edit: I see no errors in the server agent logs nor dbmail.
I ran this query: `Select * FROM sys.dm_server_services` and gave the account under the `service_account` column full control of the file in the remote server.

This is how I'm calling the sp:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'Profile',
    @recipients = 'email@email.com',
    @subject = 'Testing Attachments',
    @file_attachments = '\\servername\c$\Temp\OutputReport.pdf'
```

Error:  Msg 22051, Level 16, State 1, Line 0

Attachment file '\\servername\c$\Temp\OutputReport.pdf' is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Using an administraive share, such as C$ means the SQL Server Service Account needs to be a member of the remote machine's local Administrators group.

Instead of using the drive's administative share, create a new share at the folder where the file exists and ensure the SQL Server Service Account has access to *both* the Share *and* the file system folder where the file exists.